# JavaScript validating multiple radio selections using && operator

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use radio buttons in JavaScript to show a div ONLY when two conditions are met by selecting a specific radio button from one form and a specific button from the other. I have set up the JS as [such](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7FlOP.png). I am using the && operator to try and require both conditions to be met to run the jQuery, but it ignores the second condition.

Here is the code:

JS

```
//Front-end logic
$().ready(function(){
  $("form.vacation").submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var choice = $("input:radio[name=operator]:checked").val();
    if (choice === "ice" && "budget1") {
      $("#swiss").show();
    } else if (choice === "kayak") {
      $("#patagonia").show();
    } else if (choice === "scuba") {
      $("#hawaii").show();
    } else if (choice === "lounge") {
      $("#fiji").show();
    }

  });
});

HTML
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <form class="vacation">
        <div class="radio">
          <input type="radio" name="operator" value="ice">
          <label for="ice">I like to go ice climbing.</label>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
      <form class="vacation">
        <div class="radio">
          <input type="radio" name="operator" value="budget1">
          <label for="budget1">I have $5000 to spend.</label>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: First off, you should post your code, not a screenshot of it. Second, how could choice ever be equal to "ice" and "budget1" at the same time? Are you sure you don't need an "or" there instead? Either way, you need to have the variable, its logical operator, and the value to test against written on both sides of and/or...you can't just say "if A = B & C then", it's "if A = B or A = C then"

Comment: Is there no way to write "if A = B & C then"? I will post the code.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (choice === "ice" && "budget1")
```

is not a valid logical test and is also syntactically incorrect. Let's say, for example's sake, that it was written syntactically correct, it would look like:

```
if (choice === "ice" && choice === "budget1")
```

That is still never going to return true. For example, let's say that choice is equal to "ice"... "ice" could never be equal to both "ice" *and* "budget1" at the same time, it's just not logically possible. Rather, I think what you're looking to do is test if choice is equal to *either* "ice" *or* "budget1"...and if that were the case, the statement you want to use is:

```
if (choice === "ice" || choice === "budget1")
```

That way, if choice is equal to either one of those values, then the condition will evaluate as true.

Comment: This is a good evaluation of what can be done. I think my problem here is I have only 1 working variable where perhaps I should have two for either form and then I can use "if (choice === "ice" && choice2 === "budget1")" assuming the new variable is called choice2.

Comment: ya, if you need both radio buttons to "align" to show the div, then what you just wrote is correct

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score -1):

You have && "budget1". That is a string, so always true. So use && budget1 (assuming budget1 is a variable).